# How to package a library whose import produces side effects in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, packaging, setup.py, pypi

I am working on a python library (not mine) which looks like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── library
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── core.py
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py
```

The file `__init__.py` make use of `core.py` which itself uses `a.py` and `b.py`. The important thing to note is that `import library` has some side effets which are deliberately intended.

However, I would like to give the user the possibility to use functions of `core.py` without there being any side effects. Unfortunately, as you know, `import library.core` or `from library import core` will execute `__init__.py` (where side effects occur) anyway.

**Do you know how could I reorganize my package and the `setup.py` to solve this problem?**

---

I thought to something like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── library_core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── core.py
│   ├── a.py
│   └── b.py
└── library
    └── __init__.py  # Import library_core and apply side effects
```

I would update `setup.py` with `packages = ['library', 'library_core']`. That way, importing `library` do not change anything, but user could then import `library_core` without any side effects. Also, this would avoid duplicating code and everything would stay in the same repository.

Unfortunately, this does not work because I do not have the ability to import `library_core` from `library` since they are not in the same place in the file tree.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, this does not work because I do not have the ability to import library_core from library"* - looks like this is your main problem, what happens when you try `from library_core import core` in `library/__init__.py` ?

Comment: @Kos Actually, this could work... I tried first with `from ..library_core import *` which obviously failed, but simply `import library_core` will works **once the package is installed** with `python setup.py install`. I guess this is the way to go. So I will blank the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two package seems to be the best way.

The use of two adjacent packages can work **only if the whole library is installed** (with `python setup.py install` for example). This complicates development considerably, for unit tests for example: it was then impossible to do `import library` since `library_core` could not be found if not installed.

So, the best solution is to simply make a sub-package, and specify within the `setup.py` where `library_core` is located thanks to the `package_dir` option.

The files tree would look like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── library
    ├── __init__.py
    └── core
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── a.py
        └── b.py
```

And in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    name = 'library',
    packages = ['library', 'library.core', 'library_core'],
    package_dir = {'library_core': 'library/core'},
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you stop relying on side effects and require the user to explicitly trigger them by calling a documented function. Otherwise you are fighting a losing battle: the default is currently to trigger the side effects, and then you have to undo them if the user doesn't want them.

Comment: This is not my library, it is already very popular so there is no way for me to change the current behavior.

Comment: Common exceptions to the rule are polyfill libraries. Compare and contrast `from __future__ import absolute_import`. But yeah, it's inconvenient, for instance flake8 will complain about "unused" imports